# New-PSSession to Linux host is frozen when run under SYSTEM Account

Tags: powershell

I tried to run a Powershell Script under the System Account via Jenkins.

```
$DebugPreference = 'Continue'
$dt=get-date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm-ss-fff"
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\install\transcript-$dt.txt"
dir env:
$cmdline = $((Get-CimInstance win32_process -Filter "ProcessID=$PID" | ? { $_.processname -eq "pwsh.exe" }).commandline)
if($cmdline -like "*pwsh.exe*")
{
    write-host "Powershel 7 continue" 
    Write-Host "Before Start-session"
    $s = New-PSSession -HostName ip -UserName user -verbose  -KeyFilePath C:\.ssh\id_rsa
    Write-Host "After Start-session"
  
}else{
    Start-Process pwsh.exe -Wait -PassThru  -ArgumentList "-NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"
}    
stop-transcript
```

My Problem is that Write-Host "After Start-session" is never reached.

The first Start-Transcript shows, that the Script is started again with pwsh.exe

The second Start-Transcript shows the Output till Before Start-session.

After that there is nothing added to the Transcript and the Process keeps running.

The Script is working fine, when it is running under the Administrator Account.

How can I debug this ?

Comment: You can use `-Debug` but, im having trouble understanding what you mean. How is it never reached?

Comment: It takes indefinitely long. It simple just hangs when the New-PSSession  is executed

Comment: you can use it as a job so it doesn't wait for it to terminate. How are yu using it? i don't see the session being used

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was that the SSH fingerprint was not trusted.
When I runned the Script via a command Line instead of via Jenkins direct, i got this output:
[The authenticity of host 'ip (ip)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:gQv8WE8G04RhfNNX7pRQjVX0lPj3jNZ4JTPIDNEIGHk.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEmIX.png)

After i answered it with yes everything worked.
The Jenkings Job is now working two.